# Query different type data in to a single row with the master record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just created the following sample data to demonstrate what I am after.

[image]
[image]
I need to query the above table to get my information as 1 single row

i.e. like the following
[image]

I was planning to create two temp tables and insert the two different types of addresses seperately. Then, inner join them with the main company table. I am not sure, this is a good solution. I appreaciate if anyone share their thoughts or code to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
 Select  companyId,CompanyName,homesddress1
   ,homeaddress2,HomePostCode,OfficeAddress1,OfficeAddress2,OfficePostCode
   From tblCompany a
    Outer apply ( select address1 homesddress1, address2 homeaddress2,postcode HomePostCode 
                          From tblAddress t
                          Where AddressType='home' and t.companyid=a.companyid) 
     Outer apply (select address1 OfficeAddress1, address2 Officeaddress2,postcode OfficePostCode 
                           From tblAddress t2
                            Where AddressType='Office ' and t2.companyid=a.companyid)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple select using two outer joins.  Note that you need the joins to be outer because for some companies you may only have one address.

```
DECLARE @company TABLE (
CompanyId int,
CompanyName varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @companyAddress TABLE (
Id int,
AddressType varchar(10),
Address1 varchar(50),
Address2 varchar(50),
Postcode varchar(10),
CompanyId int
)

INSERT INTO @company VALUES (1, 'Test Company')

INSERT INTO @companyAddress VALUES (1, 'Home', '25 Street', 'City 1', 'BA3 1PE', 1)
INSERT INTO @companyAddress VALUES (2, 'Office', '25 Street', 'City 2', 'NA1 4TW', 1)

SELECT c.CompanyId, c.CompanyName, 
h.Address1 AS HomeAddress1, h.Address2 AS HomeAddress2, h.Postcode AS HomePostcode,
o.Address1 AS OfficeAddress1, o.Address2 AS OfficeAddress2, o.Postcode AS OfficePostcode
FROM @company c 
LEFT JOIN
@companyAddress h ON h.CompanyId = c.CompanyId AND h.AddressType = 'Home'
LEFT JOIN
@companyAddress o ON o.CompanyId = c.CompanyId AND o.AddressType = 'Office'
```

Comment: I think your example is showing inner joins (the default) when you said the joins need to be outer joins...

Comment: LEFT JOIN is an OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Almost Dynamic version. You just have to specify the field list in the final pivot

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,AddressType varchar(25),Address1 varchar(50),Address2 varchar(50),CompanyID int)
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'Home'  ,'25 Street','City 1',1),
(2,'Office','10 Avenue','City 2',1)
```

---

```
Declare @XML xml = (Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW)               --<<< Initial Query
;with cteBase as (
    Select ID          = R.value('@CompanyID','int')                        --<<< Key ID
          ,AddressType = R.value('@AddressType','varchar(50)')
          ,Item        = R.value('@AddressType','varchar(50)')+Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
          ,Value       = Attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
     From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(R)
     Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="CompanyID"]') as B(Attr)   --<<< Key ID
),cteDist as (Select Distinct ID,Item from cteBase
),cteComp as (
       Select A.*,B.Value 
        From  cteDist A 
        Cross Apply (Select Value=Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + Value 
                      From  cteBase 
                      Where ID=A.ID 
                        and Item=A.Item 
                      For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') ) B
)
Select * 
 From (Select * From  cteComp) as s
 Pivot (max(value) 
 For Item in (HomeID,HomeAddressType,HomeAddress1,HomeAddress2,OfficeID,OfficeAddressType,OfficeAddress1,OfficeAddress2)) as pvt
```

Returns

```
ID  HomeID  HomeAddressType HomeAddress1    HomeAddress2    OfficeID    OfficeAddressType   OfficeAddress1  OfficeAddress2
1   1       Home            25 Street       City 1          2           Office             10 Avenue        City 2
```